# Publishing feature service from local file geodatabase using ArcGIS for Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, file-geodatabase, arcgis-10.4, feature-service

How is it possible to publish the feature service from a local file geodatabase i.e. not using an **Enterprise geodatabase such as Oracle via ArcSDE**.

When i try to create a feature service it gives me error:

> Feature Service require a registered database

and i have no database installed. i am copying my geodatabase to ArcGIS Server.

When i try to place my file geodatabase on network that is shared location it gives me error that:

> Feature Data Source is not supportted

Software that I am using:

ArcGIS for Desktop 10.4.1 
ArcGIS for Server 10.4.1
Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: Yes. That is very doable. You just need to make the location of the data available to your ArcGIS Server on your network.

Comment: I have registered a folder which was shared on my network. After adding data it genereated error that "Layer data source is not supported". Do you know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Please avoid asking Boolean questions, especially "Is it possible" questions, whose answers are almost always, "Yes."  Instead, focus on "HOW is it possible..." being sure to provide the **exact** versions of **all** software, along with a description of what you have tried.  All responses to questions in comments should be made by improving the question to include the new information. Please do not hide important details in comments.

Comment: All environemnts are added.

Comment: An "exact" version of Oracle would specify the exact product. "11g" spans two families.  The description of what you've tried is still missing,

Comment: I have clearly mentioned i am not using oracle database. I am using local file geodatabase.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, you **need** a registered database with the server to publish a **feature service**. This [help link](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/copying-data-to-the-server-automatically-when-publishing.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_3DDF21D6C99748179085FD64F650EE34) has more information. The last section of this [topic explains](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/linux/what-is-a-feature-service-.htm) at the highest level, the steps required to publish a feature service.

If you dont have SQL Server, or Oracle, or another *Enterprise* database, you can setup SQL Express workgroup to act as your registered database. This [topic provides information](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/register-workgroup-geodatabase-with-arcgis-server.htm).

Comment: So, you are saying that i can not directly copy my file geodatabase to arcgis for server ?? and publish a feature service. I heared that this is possible in ARcGIS 10.4+ versions.

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of [publishing a hosted features](http://server.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/use/publish-features.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_F878B830119B4443A8CFDA8A96AAF7D1) from a file gdb to portal?

Comment: If you want a **feature** service your data either needs to be in a referenced enterprise database, OR you need to setup a managed database in the datastore. (This database can be enterprise or a sql express workgroup). **file geodatabase** data itself cannot be the source data to a **feature** service